# DIV won't move down with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got two big DIVs under each other. In these DIVs are two smaller ones. The first one is always visible and the second one should slideDown with jQuery when clicked on the first one. Well, it does slide down, but it doesn't move the next big DIV located under itself.

In code it looks kinda like this:

```
<div class="big">
 <div class="small_up">
 </div>
 <div class="small_down">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="big">
 <div class="small_up">
 </div>
 <div class="small_down">
 </div>
```

In those "small" DIVs are more, absolute positioned DIVs.

In case you want to see the whole, real code:

```
<div class="post post-texts" status="closed">
    <div class="post-top">
        <div class="avatar"><img src="img/avatar.png"></div>
        <a href="http://parislemon.com/post/15604811641/why-i-hate-android" class="quote" target="empty">
            <div class="quote">
                »I hate Android for the same reason that Severus Snape hates Harry Potter - the very sight reminds me of something so beautiful, that was taken. Except it’s worse. It’s as if Harry Potter has grown up to become Voldemort. «
            </div>
        </a>
        <div class="buttons">
            <img class="recite" src="img/recite.png" />
            <img class="like" src="img/like.png" />
            <img class="facebook" src="img/facebook.png" />
            <img class="twitter" src="img/twitter.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-bottom">
            <div class="post-stats" >
                <div class="recite-counter">15</div>
                <p class="recite-counter-text">Recites</p>
                <div class="like-counter">36</div>
                <p class="like-counter-text">Likes</p>
            </div>
            <div class="comments comments-texts">
                <div class="single-comment">
                    <div class="avatar-comment"><img src="img/avatar-comment.png" /></div>
                    <div class="comment-content">
                    Patrick -
                    <span class="comment">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur  At vero eos et accusam et just At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren.o duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren. sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor.  At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren.</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="comment-time">
                        about 10 minutes ago
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="single-comment">
                    <div class="avatar-comment"><img src="img/avatar-comment.png" /></div>
                    <div class="comment-content">
                    Patrick -
                    <span class="comment">stfu</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="comment-time">
                        about 5 minutes ago
                    </div>
                </div>      
            <div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('div.post').click(function() {
    $('div.post-bottom').slideDown(500);
});
```

CSS:

```
div.timeline {
    position: absolute;
    top: 420px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -425px;
    width: 850px;
}
div.post {
    position: relative;
    height: 170px;
    width: 850px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
div.post-texts {
    background-color: #196074;
}
div.avatar {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
}
div.quote {
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px;
    top: 17px;
    width: 650px;
    font-family: DroidSans;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 23px;
}
div.buttons {
    position: absolute;
    top: 135px;
    left: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 110px;
}
div.post-bottom {
    position: relative;
    top: 170px;
    width: 853px;
    display: none;
}
div.post-stats {
    position: relative;
    width: 426px;
    background-color: #196074;
    padding: 50px 0px 50px 20px;
}
div.recite-counter, div.like-counter {
    height: 25px;
    width: 35px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: DroidSansBold;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #196074;
    padding-top: 9px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
div.like-counter {
    margin-top: 20px;
}


div.comments {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 426px;
    width: 427px;
    /* border-left: 3px solid #fff; */
}
div.comments-texts {
    background-color: #196074;
}
div.single-comment {
    width: 400px;
    min-height: 55px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}
div.avatar-comment {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 10px;
}
div.comment-content {
    font-family: DroidSansBold;
    font-size: 12px;;
    padding: 9px 5px 10px 53px;
    line-height: 15px;
    color: #fff;
}
div.comment-time {
    font-family: DroidSans;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0px 0px 10px 53px;
}
```

Shortly: The DIV above slides over the one which is under this DIV. The DIV under it should just slide down too.

Comment: i made working fiddle with given code for help( but no images ) : http://jsfiddle.net/ZXs56/

Answer (score 1):

try to change all positions to "relative" and see if works.

Comment: This is correct. @Patrick, remember that Absolutely positioned elements are just that: absolutely positioned. If you want them to be positioned (and repositioned) relative to their siblings they have to be relatively positioned or you have to move them manually.

Comment: Alright, I just changed everything to relative but it still doesn't work. I think I'll just start all over, I've copied the comment section out of an old project of mine. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you don't have any declared height on `div.comments`. It's absolutely positioned and therefore will not automatically take up any height in the layout unless you have a specific height declared for it. Try adding `border: 1px solid red` around `.post-bottom` and a different color border to `.comments` to see exactly how much space they're occupying (although using Firebug to inspect these elements would be better).

One thing that is *always* true for absolutely positioned elements is that they will *never* add height or width to their parent element.

I think you may want to have the '.post-stats' div be absolutely positioned and the .comments div be relatively positioned as that will be the element that needs to adapt to a variable number of elements (and therefore variable height).

Also keep in mind that using `top:` or `bottom:` can give you some confusing layout problems with regard to element heights and how they push each other down or up in vertical space if you don't account for the increase/decrease in positioning either with extra (or negative as the case may be) height or extra margin or padding for it's parent element.